# Create SQL Query in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am new to Laravel but I would like to create this Query(MySQL):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ce.empresa_id,
            CONCAT(ce.nombre, ' ', ce.apellido) AS nombre,
            ce.grupo_contable
        FROM
            cliente_empresa AS ce
        UNION
            SELECT
                cc.empresa_id,
                cc.nombre,
                cc.grupo_contable
            FROM
                cuenta_contable AS cc
            UNION
                SELECT
                    cci.empresa_id,
                    cci.grupo_iva AS nombre,
                    cci.cuenta_contable AS grupo_contable
                FROM
                    cuenta_contables_iva AS cci
    ) AS cuentasContables
WHERE
    cuentasContables.empresa_id = 1
AND (cuentasContables.nombre LIKE '%a%'
OR cuentasContables.grupo_contable LIKE '%%')
```

Looking at Documentation I can't find the proper way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Here you go contains everything you will need https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: @Maantje http://prntscr.com/gpixdv

Comment: What have you tried already (any code?), I'm willing to help just want to see some effort from your side.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6U9N7VLV Thanks and sorry, I forgot to post this.

I get this when running that code: http://prntscr.com/gpj3uo

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for a query that the ORM can't manage, you would probably want to simply call `\DB::raw`:

```
$results = \DB::table('users')
     ->select(\DB::raw(/* your stuff here */))
```

However in your case, you might want to consider sticking to the ORM. It looks like you might want to try something like:

```
$first = DB::table('cliente_empresa')
        ->where('empresa_id', '=', 1);

$second = DB::table('cuenta_contable')
        ->where('empresa_id', '=', 1);

$results = DB::table('cuenta_contables_iva')
        ->where('empresa_id', '=', 1)
        ->union($first)
        ->union($second)
        ->get();
```

Obviously, you'll need to put your `SELECT` column statements in there as well.